# how to set the pagination for the gallery?

Tags: php, wordpress, pagination

I replaced the standard WordPress gallery of their own. I can not bind to the pagination of the gallery. post_per_page not working.

```
  remove_shortcode("gallery");
    add_shortcode("gallery","my_gallery");

    function my_gallery($atts){
        $img_id = explode(',', $atts['ids']);
        if(!$img_id[0]) {
            return '<div class="no-img-gallery">No images</div>';
        }

        $html = '<div class="gallery-my">';
        foreach ($img_id as $item){
            $img_data = get_posts(array(
                'posts_per_page' => '8',
                'paged' => ( get_query_var('paged') ? get_query_var('paged') : 1 ),
                'p' => $item,
                'post_type' => 'attachment'
            ));

            $img_desc = $img_data[0]->post_content;
            $img_caption = $img_data[0]->post_excerpt;
            $img_title = $img_data[0]->post_title;
            $img_thumb = wp_get_attachment_image_src($item);
            $img_full = wp_get_attachment_image_src($item,medium);


            $html .="
            <div class='item-gallery'>
                <a href='{$img_full[0]}'>
                    <img src='{$img_thumb[0]}' width='{$img_thumb[1]}' height='{$img_thumb[2]}' alt='{$img_title}'>
                <div class='desc-wrap'>
                        <strong class='title-img'>{$img_title}</strong>
                        <span class='desc-img'>{$img_desc}</span>
                    </div>
                </a> 
            </div>";

        }

        $html .= "</div>";


        return $html;
    }
```

Tell me what to add to the code to make it work. Or change it

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
'posts_per_page' => 8,
```

without the apostrophes around the 8.